# Check all values of tuple in list

Tags: python-2.7, renpy

I have a list set up like this in Python (via Ren'Py):

```
[('nc',nc,'test test test'),('nr',nr,'test test test')]
```

The 'nr' is a string, naturally, and the nr (without the quotes) is an object. The last bit is a string.

Now, what I would like to be able to do, is compare the whole tuple in an if.

Something like this:

```
if (char,charobj,message) not in list:
    #do stuff
```

This does not work - it still does stuff regardless. So... how do I compare all of the items to each of the tuples in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm...

I guess that you `charobj` may be a class you implemented yourself.
To allow Python to perform a *meaningful* equality comparison an not just a *blind* comparison, you have to overload the default methods for that like :

- `__eq__(self, other)`
- `__gt__(self, other)`
- `__lt__(self, other)`
- ...

More information there : https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Anyway, I made some tests and it works fine with literal and built-in types.
I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 10 (x64).

```
nr = 4
nc = 2
list = [('nc',nc,'test test test'),('nr',nr,'test test test')]

if ('nc', 2, 'test test test') in list:
    print('OK')
else:
    print('KO')
```

actually prints `OK`.

I tried with `not in`, it prints `KO`.

I also tried to replace the literals with variables and it seems to work too.

```
nr = 4
nc = 2
list = [('nc',nc,'test test test'),('nr',nr,'test test test')]

_nc = 'nc'
_message = 'test test test'
if (_nc, nc, _message) in list:
    print('OK')
else:
    print('KO')
```

also prints `OK`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hm, the charobj is the built-in Renpy Character()-object, actually... but if what you say there is true, it should work correctly like it is now as well... I will test a bit more.

Comment: It seems it's working - it's just that Renpy's console was bugging it out, and causing the .append / .remove to not trigger correctly.